# How to achieve tags related functionality in android?

Tags: android, layout

friends,

i want to perform functionality same like stackoverflow tags as we do normally creating a question separated by commas in android.

i know we have auto complete text view in android any one suggest me can i use it for multi selection?

or any useful way to achieve this?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be achieve through two ways 
i devised my own machanism so may b you people have better approach than me please share too.

1) simple 
2) advance

1) in simple we can use autocomplete text view and only use single tag with hard coded values which is limitation.

2) i have used a popup page with a Edittext and add button on top and listview with checkboxes below it.
fixed items i have already loaded into list view with checkboxes so that i could select multiple tags.

and in case of if i want to add my custom tag then i use that edit text above list view and store it in temporary data and 
then finally using bundle i show selected values where i want seperated by commas.

thats it.